# laravel 4 error on line that dosn't exist in routes.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I have a problem that is killing me, help me please.

I worked on a project in laravel 4 when I forgot a semicolon in routes.php, the screen errors laravel warned me, but after adding the semicolon the error was still there, so I deleted the 'entire block of code with the error, but laravel still gave me an error on that line that is no longer there. So I deleted the file routes.php, but laravel still gave me the same error, now I have put back routes.php but the views give me strange results, and I still get the error about missing semicolon.

I apologize for my wrong english.
Thanks a lot.

EDIT: ok, i am sorry.. but I did not know what code to write, because this error is so strange

The error is:
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…/­app/­routes.php116

syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH

```
Route::post('/realtime_callback',  function() 
{

    $post = Input::all();
    $a = print_r($myString, true);
    file_put_contents('activity.log', "\r\n".$myString[0]["subscription_id"], FILE_APPEND)
    /*line 116*/foreach($myString[0]['data'] as $item)
        file_put_contents('text.log', "\r\naa".$item, FILE_APPEND);
```

But the actuale code is:

```
Route::post('/realtime_callback',  function() {

$post = Input::all();

/*line 116*/$evento = Evento::where('subscription_id', '=', $post[0]["subscription_id"]);

$search = new SearchTag($evento->tag);

$response = json_decode($search->sendRequest($evento->min_id));

foreach($response->data as $item) {

    $photo_exist = Photo::where('id', '=', $item->id);

    if(is_null($photo_exist))
        $photo = new Photo();
        $photo->id = $item->id;
        $photo->eve_cod = $evento->name;
        $photo->save();
}

Evento::where('name', '=', $event_name)->update(array('min_id' => $response->pagination->min_tag_id));
});
```

The strange results means that the view show different result from previus, almost all pages bring me back to page 404, olse the / that corresponds to

```
Route::get('/', function(){

//return Redirect::to('users/register');
return "hello";
});
```

Comment: we need more details.. please write the errors you get + show us some code... and check that you not using some caching like apc or opCache

Comment: please post the error, and your routes.php

Comment: I have add more information, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

In this code block

```
Route::post('/realtime_callback',  function() 
{
    $post = Input::all();
    $a = print_r($myString, true);
    // This line is missing the semicolon at the end
    file_put_contents('activity.log', "\r\n".$myString[0]["subscription_id"], FILE_APPEND)
    /*line 116*/foreach($myString[0]['data'] as $item)
    file_put_contents('text.log', "\r\naa".$item, FILE_APPEND);
```

You missed a semicolon in the line where `file_put_contents`, just before the `foreach` line.